# Server-side conversion of raster images to vector images

Tags: php, image-processing, vectorization

I would like to convert images that have been uploaded by the user (in various formats and conditions) to a vector image format such as .eps. I'm primarily working in PHP.

What options exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coverstion of SVG into PNG/JPEG/BMP and Vice Versa? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021756/coverstion-of-svg-into-png-jpeg-bmp-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a small number of autotracing software projects released under GPU (for example, [POTRACE](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) that you could run via system commands. I can't attest to their quality. Tracing almost always requires some element of human supervision to avoid things looking like a mess of broken pottery, but you won't know until you try. Rather than triggering the tracer via PHP, I would use PHP simply to save incoming images to a temporary folder and then, through cronjob (one- or two-per-minute), crank through the holding folder in batches (you could pace it that way and avoid it being used as a way to DoS your site).

I'm thinking of doing something slightly similar (though not graphic related) for an upcoming project, and I'm considering doing all my heavy lifting on a desktop machine, which would fetch all incoming files and process them before FTPing them back to the server. I'm somewhat nervous about having any complex resource-intensive script like this running on a web server.

Answer (score 2):

Definitelly you can do this with the Inkscape

here is the list of formats it supports [What formats can Inkscape import/export?](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_formats_can_Inkscape_import.2Fexport.3F)

and it can be of course used with the command line or exec() command [Can Inkscape be used from the command line?](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Can_Inkscape_be_used_from_the_command_line.3F)

Answer (score 2):

Imagetracer is a free and open source (Public Domain) library and application which can be used on the server side. Disclaimer: I made these.

You can use **ImageTracer.jar** from

https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjava

like this with PHP:

`<?php exec("java -jar ImageTracer.jar input.png outfilename output.svg"); ?>`

You can also use the JavaScript version with Node.js on the server side, here's the example code:

https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs/tree/master/nodecli

<s>https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs/blob/master/nodetest/nodetest.js</s>

Answer (score -8):

PHP is not an image editor. It is a **hypertext** preprocessor.

You have to move to serverfault.com, or even better on some image processing resource, and ask there for some command line utility that can be run from PHP using the `system()` command.

Comment: I understand the PHP is not an image editor. PHP can interface with many useful libs such as GD and ImageMagik without relying on system().

Comment: @Jon I can't say GD is whatever useful, but in general - yes. It can even control a hydraulic press via com port. It doesn't mean that questions about hydraulic presses are suitable here.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel unless I'm missing something, PHP is Turing Complete, so you could program anything computable on it, and estimating vectors to represent a raster image is certainly computable. I also don't see how this question is different from the myriad of other questions that have "use xxx library" as a valid response (e.g. "What regex do I use to parse the src of images on this page in .Net?" -> "You should skip regexes and use the HtmlAgilityPack").

Comment: Oh, sure, @jball you are welcome to write a tracer in PHP, lol :)

Comment: A community delete-answer feature will be useful to help clear this type of content from otherwise useful pages.