# How can I convert png to svg using Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, npm, angular2-directives

I need to Convert some images(png/jpg) to **SVG** using Angular2 or higher,
so that using these **SVG** files, I can create an SVG sprite map.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [Tour], [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Show some code you've tried :)

Comment: There's probably no easy way to do that. This one might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022774/conversion-of-jpeg-to-svg-in-javascript Although, i think it would be better to just create the SVG in some program designed for it.

Comment: If the goal is to end up with a sprite map, make a PNG sprite map. If the goal is to end up with SVG images, you'll want to design those from the start as vector images (some bitmap-to-vector conversion tools like `potrace` do exist, but the results need a lot of manual cleanup for all but the simplest images).  In neither case would Angular be relevant.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something like this with Ionic. I want to use a js library to trace a bitmap to a svg approximation. I have been trying to use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagetracerjs but I'm having difficulty getting it to work in Angular. Can anyone help?